# Oracle datebase connectced through Entity Framework ( C# VS 2015 database-first) error

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm a bit new to Entity Framework and I am trying to connect to the Oracle Database through Entity Framework.
Using Visual Studio 2015 Entity framework wizard, I created a database by reverse engineering our current database.
When I start debugging a had an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibraryDLL.DAL;
namespace LibraryDLL
{
    public class Class1
    {     
        public void testDB()
        {
            using (EntitiesDBTest db = new EntitiesDBTest())
            {
                List<BOOK> books = db.BOOKS.ToList(); // <-- error
                List<USER> users = db.USERS.ToList();
                List<HISTORY> histories = db.HISTORies.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code below was generated from a template.

```
namespace LibraryDLL.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class BOOK
    {
        public BOOK()
        {
            this.HISTORies = new HashSet<HISTORY>();
        }

        public int BOOKID { get; set; }
        public string AUTHORFIRSTNAME { get; set; }
        public string AUTHORLASTNAME { get; set; }
        public string TITLE { get; set; }
        public string SHORTDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string LONGDESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<HISTORY> HISTORies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have included following configs in your App.Config file

```
<configuration>
 <entityFramework>
  <providers>
   <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

and

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

**EDIT**:

It's also a good idea to move this

```
<startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
```

down to the bottom of the configuration tag.